# An error occurred while loading the model. No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'. Error in Databricks classification model serving endpoint

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow, mlops

I'm currently struggling with setting up Serving endpoints for classification models in Azure Databricks.

I've tried this for a few different classification models, such as the following example provided by databricks themselves, using automl:
https://docs.databricks.com/_extras/notebooks/source/machine-learning/automl-classification-example.html

My Databricks environment details are as follows:
Pricing Tier: Premium
Location: West Europe
Cluster Policy: Personal Compute,
Databricks Runtime Version: 12.2 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)
Access Mode: Single Access

The model is created and registered to the model registry with no issues, but when I follow the GUI to create the endpoint, it gives the following errors in the logs:
Events:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q585z.png)
Logs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBpSb.png)

I get this same "An error occurred while loading the model. No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'" for a variety of different classification models.
Most other articles are not Databricks specific, so reference incompatibilities between Pandas versions, but Pandas isn't specified as a module in the requirements package of the model, so this isn't configurable when creating the serving endpoint.
Of these other articles, it is suggested Pandas 2.0 is a possible cause, but running pandas.**version** shows that this is running 1.4.2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy1Zi.png)

Has anyone seen something similar before and is able to advise on a solution or tips to debug?

Many thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below approach to add library to conda file.

```
cd = {
"channels":["conda-forge"],
"dependencies": ["python=3.9.5","pip<=21.2.4","pandas==1.5.3",
{
"pip":["mlflow<3,>=2.1","cffi==1.15.0","cloudpickle==2.0.0","psutil==5.8.0","scikit-learn==1.0.2","typing-extensions==4.1.1"]
},],
"name": "mlflow-env"
}

with mlflow.start_run():
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    iris_train = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=7, random_state=0)
    clf.fit(iris_train, iris.target)
    mlflow.sklearn.log_model(clf, "iris_rf", registered_model_name="model-libs-9741",conda_env=cd)
```

Output will be,

```
Registered model 'model-libs-9741' already exists. Creating a new version of this model... Created version '2' of model 'model-libs-9741'.
```

Since i have already registered the model second version is created.

Below is the dependencies before adding custom conda-env.

[image]

After executing the above code, we get another version of model having `pandas` library in Conda file.

[image]

After registering the model, create serving endpoint with the version having pandas dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response on this, Jayashankar. This did indeed help when I replicated your example and I was able to apply this to my specific situation.

This however showed me further errors, with other missing modules appearing in the Service Logs.

I tried debugging a bit further, but rolling back to runtime 11.3 LTS ML runtime and recreating my models this way proved successful. I'll have a dig around to see if there is any more evidence on the cause of this, or if it is a 12.2 LTS ML runtime bug.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are talking about the exact error in their [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/machine-learning/automl/train-ml-model-automl-api.html#no-module-named-pandascoreindexesnumeric).

> ### No module named ‘pandas.core.indexes.numeric
>
> ##### When serving a model built using AutoML with Model Serving, you may get the error: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.
>
> This is due to an incompatible pandas version between AutoML and the model serving endpoint environment. You can resolve this error by running the [add-pandas-dependency.py script](https://docs.databricks.com/_extras/documents/add-pandas-dependency.py). The script edits the requirements.txt and conda.yaml for your logged model to include the appropriate pandas dependency version: pandas==1.5.3.
>
> 1. Modify the script to include the run_id of the MLflow run where your model was logged.
> 2. Re-registering the model to the MLflow model registry.
> 3. Try serving the new version of the MLflow model.